# Did Adam and Chava have a house in Eden?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-bereishit, adam

I remember Adam was put in Eden and Chavah was created and they hid in bushes, but I don't recall them building a house or a shelter.

I also remember a Midrash saying G-d made a Chupah for them and then ... Adam knew his wife. As it happened still in Eden I presume they had shelter or something else.

Do the sources mention anything about a house in Eden?

Comment: dont take all that too literally

Comment: @michael This. Very much. Even had a short conversation with a non-Jewish Azeri neighboor (a good, honest, simple man as far as I can recognize). I honestly think that back then, the physicalities and limitations that we know of today simply didn't apply.

Comment: @michael what heresy! not taking Genesis 1 and 2 literally??

Comment: @DoubleAA,not sure if you are jk or not?

Comment: @sam CYLOR for psak

Comment: Psak?,this is not a halachic question ,I am just wondering if ur comment is a jk based off the Rambam,or you think it's true heresy

Comment: definitely not to be taken literally. according to the midrash Adam's stature was from the earth to the heavens. kabalists say his body was not even physical.